# Betweenness Centrality: How Long Does Mathematica Take?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

A simple maths problem.

If I have a disk of unit radius and place within it $N$ nodes such that the node density $\rho$ is given by

$$\rho=\frac{N}{\pi R^{2}}=\frac{N}{\pi}$$

then connect each node up to anybody within a Euclidean distance 0.4, how long does Mathematica take to evaluate the betweenness centrality of all $N$ nodes? I think it uses Brandes' algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality).

I've tried submitting a job to a supercomputer taking $\rho=1000$ and I'm not sure if this is going to take a day or a year....can anyone estimate the waiting time specifically for the $\rho=1000$ case, or as a function of $\rho$?

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is $O(|V|^3)$. With $|V|=3000$ it's likely to complete very quickly. I don't expect this to take very long.

Comment: Does Mathematica use Floyd-Warshall or Brandes?

Comment: Your question(s) might be better suited for mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, assuming Mathematica uses Brandes' algorithm for unweighted graphs, the time complexity is $\mathcal{O}\left(nm\right)$ where $n$ is the total number of nodes and $m$ the number of edges.

As such, when $\rho\approx1000$, $N=3141$: every node connects to every other within a radius of $r_{0}$, such that the $m$ scales algebraically with $r_{0}$ for fixed $N$.

With  $r_{0}=0.4$, Brandes takes over a day, but with  $r_{0}=0.07$ (which should just about ensure the network connects), Brandes takes about 4 minutes (when run on a ~3Ghz processor).